# Change width of selectbox if no value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

can someone help me please with creating little script in jQuery to make select box width bigger when is there no value? Here is code for my selectbox

```
<td class="value">
    <select>
        <option value="">
            Select one
        </option>
        <option value="100-g"  selected='selected'>
            100 g
        </option>
        <option value="200-g" >
            200 g
        </option>
    </select>
</td>
```

and I need to make this: `.summary table.variations .value { width: 300px;  }` Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/2qn0d7rg/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').on('change',function(){
        var select = $(this),
            cell = select.closest('td');
        if(select.val()){
            cell.removeClass('large');
        }else{
            cell.addClass('large');
        }
    });
});
```

Is it what you want ?

Comment: yes, but i want to add that large class to td before. So it will looks like `<td class="value large">`

Comment: Ok I changed my jsfiddle & my answer to put the class on the `td` instead of the `select`. Is it ok now ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select {
    min-width:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give min-width , so it will apply even if no value.

```
select {
   min-width:300px;
}
option {
    min-width:300px;
}
```